# Proper way to specify static files path for express static middleware

Tags: node.js, express

What is the difference between

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

and

```
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

I've seen both formats used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With given examples:

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

and

```js
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

there is no difference. You can use first argument as **virtual path prefix** (so path does not actually exist in the file system), for example:

```js
app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

Will cause that static files (e.g. `http://localhost:3000/static/css/style.css`) will be server from `/static` path, but files will be in  `public` directory.

Comment: Note that if you are running express app from directory, you can use ``app.use(express.static('public'))``